# Replace values with subseting operator [

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
set.seed(1)

df_1 <- data.frame(x = replicate(n = 2, expr = sample(x = 1:3, size = 20, replace = T)), 
               y = as.factor(sample(x = 1:5, size = 20, replace = TRUE)))
```

I want replace the numbers `>=2` by `9` in `x.1` and `x.2` simultaneoulsy:

```
df_1[df_1$x.1, df_1$x.2 >= 2] <- 9
```

> Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, df_1$x.1, df_1$x.2 >= 2, value = 9) : 
>     duplicate subscripts for columns

And replace the number `3` by `99` in `y`.

```
df_1$y[df_1$y %in% c('3')] <- 99
```

> Warning message:
>   In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, df_1$y %in% c("3"), value = c(2L, 5L, 2L,  :
>     invalid factor level, NA generated

Tks.

Comment: Does y need to be a factor? Is there any reason why you can't work with it as a regular numeric value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `replace`

```
df_1[1:2] <- replace(df_1[1:2], df_1[1:2] >=2, 9)
```

---

Or another option is create the logical matrix on the subset of 'x.' columns, extract the values and assign it to 9

```
df_1[1:2][df_1[1:2] >= 2] <- 9
```

For changing the `factor`, we either needs to call `factor` again or add `levels` beforehand

```
levels(df_1$y) <- c(levels(df_1$y), "99")
df_1$y
#[1] 4 4 4 2 4 1 1 4 1 2 3 2 2 5 2 1 3 3 4 3
#Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 99

df_1$y[df_1$y == '3'] <- '99'
df_1$y
#[1] 4  4  4  2  4  1  1  4  1  2  99 2  2  5  2  1  99 99 4  99
@#Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 99
```

Or as @thelatemail mentioned, if we are dropping the `levels` while doing the replacement

```
levels(df_1$y)[levels(df_1$y) == '3'] <- "99"
```

---

Or can use `fct_recode` from `forcats`

```
library(forcats)
df_1$y <- fct_recode(df_1$y, "99" = "3")
```

Comment: I need a solution with `[`.

Comment: For the factor `y` there is no solution with `[`?

Comment: @neves for `factor`, `levels` needs to be updated or call `factor` again.  Updated the post

Comment: You could also overwrite the factor `levels` directly - `levels(df_1$y)[levels(df_1$y) == 3] <- "9"`